# What is maximum possible current in neutral wire in three phase connector?

Tags: current, three-phase, neutral

What is the maximum possible current in neutral wire in eg. 3x16A three phase connector? Is it possible that current leads or lags more than 90 degrees?

Edit:

Could the maximum be

16A∠0° + 16A∠(120°-90°) + 16A∠(-120°+90°) = 43.7A∠0°

Found a vector calculator https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vector-calculator.html

16A∠0° + 16A∠120° = 16A∠60°

16A∠0° + 16A∠-120° = 16A∠-60°

16A∠0° + +16A∠120° + 16A∠-120° = 0A∠0°

Comment: Under extreme conditions it could be 16 amps and, under normal operation it could be virtually any phase angle you can think of.